# Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component in cypress unit testcases

Tags: reactjs, cypress, uncaught-exception, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to write "unit-test" for components in react with cypress.
Followed the link [cypress docs on component testing](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/cypress-component-testing-react/)

when I wrote testcase for a component and tried to run with "npx cypress open-ct"
then getting the above error (question title)...
Note: for login oAuth2 is implemented !!!
My index.spec.js file is

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from '@cypress/react';
import User from './index';

describe('User component', ()=>{
    before('loginApi', ()=>{
        cy.login();  
        //login() has login-logic and setting localStorage (placed in "commands.js" file)  
        //even if cy.login() is commented, error is same (so guessing this not reason of error)
    })
    it('Mount user', () => {            
        mount(<User />); 
    });
})
```

Observation1: on cypress browser under TEST BODY "mount" value is <Unknown.../>
Observation2: [Network tab] User component makes api-call and failing with 401
(#known token issue, even fails with right token)

Find attached error screenshot. [image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

After some beating around I found out...

1. **mount <Unknown... />** basically thrown in the case, if you have not added all the dependencies which are used in respective index.jsx file.
2. **useNavigation() may be used only in context is thrown in the case**, if you are missing BrowserRouter dependency the way you have used in your routing page (either one)
   `import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';`
   `import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

   ```
   import * as React from 'react';  
   import { mount } from '@cypress/react';  
   import User from './index';  
   import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';   

   describe('User component', ()=>{
      it('Mount user', () => {   
         const onSubmit= cy.stub();  
         //or any other function which is probably used by ur component         
         mount(
           <Router>      
              <User onSumbit={onSubmit}/>
           </Router>
         ); 
      });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what [CodeWorld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69998243/12566292) said, this error occurs because your component depends on `react-router-dom` so you have to tell Cypress to mount your component whilst been wrapped inside `BrowserRouter`.

Personally, I like to create a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#__docusaurus_skipToContent_fallback) to abstract the mounting process (useful for providers that are nested):

```
// cypress/support/commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('mountWithProviders', (children: ReactNode) => {
  cy.mount(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AnotherProvider>
        <AnotherProvider2>{children}</AnotherProvider2>
      </AnotherProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
});

// index.spec.js
cy.mountWithProviders(<Signin />);
```